# Poorly Painted Rebus (2)

Tags: rebus

[image]

This is a...
<sub>The answer to this riddle is a common object, phrase, or idiom</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rebus represents

> "hit below the belt".

Comment: Yep, that's it!